# I need my android app to show multiple notifications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I didn't find a single solution on the internet that solves the problem.

```
    int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(Common.getStringSharedPreference(context, "NOTIFICATION_ID", "ID", "1"));

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.app_logo, message, System.currentTimeMillis());
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = null;
    notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyLawyerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(ExtrasKeys.ITEM_OBJECT, (Serializable) object);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.sound = Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    Common.putStringSharedPreference(context, "NOTIFICATION_ID", "ID", ""+(notificationId+1));
```

**Note that I am using a device with lollipop for testing.**

Comment: hasan you should use different id for each notification ...... notificationManager.notify( HERE , notification);

Comment: Thank you @koutuk he provied an answer before your original comment by 5 sec :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the number for multiple notification like

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: so there where the id should go! and not here PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, notificationIntent, 0); so what is this one that I am setting?

Comment: The first parameter of the notificationManger.notify method is a unique ID for the notification within your application, the second parameter is the notification object we created using the builder method.

Comment: Tested and worked :) I will accept the answer when I am allowed in 5 minutes!